# AttributeError: 'QTextBrowser' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I'm trying to put functions to my UI that has `lineEdit` where i could type and a **SEND** button which can then forward the text to the  `textBrowser` to display, but i'm getting the error.

AttributeError: 'QTextBrowser' object has no attribute 'get'

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

import design

class ExampleApp(QtGui.QDialog, design.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)                                     
        self.sendButton.clicked.connect(self.send_message)

    def send_message(self):
        text_contents = self.lineEdit.get()
        self.textBrowser.insert(text_contents)
```

I may have used things wrong, correct me where i did mistakes.

design.ui here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>441</width>
    <height>531</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>441</width>
    <height>531</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>441</width>
    <height>531</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Chatbot</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIcon">
   <iconset>
    <normaloff>../python gui/chatbot.png</normaloff>../python gui/chatbot.png</iconset>
  </property>
  <property name="accessibleName">
   <string/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>340</x>
     <y>450</y>
     <width>91</width>
     <height>81</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset>
     <normaloff>../python gui/mic.png</normaloff>../python gui/mic.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="iconSize">
    <size>
     <width>50</width>
     <height>50</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="checkable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="autoRepeat">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>450</y>
     <width>221</width>
     <height>81</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>12</pointsize>
     <weight>75</weight>
     <bold>true</bold>
    </font>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="textBrowser">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>441</width>
     <height>441</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <family>MS Shell Dlg 2</family>
     <pointsize>16</pointsize>
     <weight>75</weight>
     <bold>true</bold>
    </font>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="sendButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>240</x>
     <y>450</y>
     <width>91</width>
     <height>81</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <family>Lucida Console</family>
     <pointsize>16</pointsize>
     <weight>75</weight>
     <bold>true</bold>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="statusTip">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="whatsThis">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>SEND</string>
   </property>
   <property name="iconSize">
    <size>
     <width>22</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </size>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: if self.lineEdit is a QLineEdit then change `get` to `text`, but as I think it is a QTextBrowser then change it to `toPlainText`

Comment: @eyllanesc changed those two but i got the error: 
TypeError: QTextEdit.toPlainText(): too many arguments

Comment: You can show your .ui file

Comment: @eyllanesc check i added .ui file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lineEdit is a QLineEdit so if you need to get the text you must use the `text()` method, and textBrowser is a QTextBrowser and to add text you must use `append()`

```
def send_message(self):
    text_contents = self.lineEdit.text()
    self.textBrowser.append(text_contents)
```